# tool for visualizing simple 2d shapes

Tags: 2d, tools

I'm drawing simple 2D line shapes using coordinate sets (for example, `moveTo(x,y)` `drawTo(x,y)`). I would like a tool that is like a sheet of graph paper.  When I click on intersection points it records the coordinates I clicked and prints them to a dialog box.

Hopefully it would be a simple website in javascript or something. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: This is kind of a which tech to use question. There really isn't a single *correct* answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tool](http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/demo/linepolygon.htm) allows you to point and click to select points, and then 
draw a Line, Polyline or Polygon. It will print out the points data required.

[image]

---

There's quite a few out there that offer a similar functionality, but they're meant for use on maps. [This one](http://www.mapmash.in/kmlpolygon.html) is a decent one that displays point information right away.

[image]

---

[This one](http://ucsmp.uchicago.edu/secondary/curriculum/advanced-algebra/demos/polyplotter-aa/) is a little bit the opposite, you mark the points and it draws them, however, you can then use matrices to transform the shape you've drawn. (You may want to use it [here](http://ucsmp.uchicago.edu/secondary/curriculum/advanced-algebra/demos/polyplotter-aa/polyplotter.swf), as it's not cut off by bad page margins)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple tool that allows for point drawing, image overlaying, and also matrix transforms.  It's open source on github.  Here's the demo:

http://bmx-pointtool.meteor.com/

[image: BMX-PointTool screenshot]